# Android Gradle: different signingConfigs for different product variants

Tags: android, gradle, signing

My project has 2 flavors, each of which uses a different signingConfig - but only for the release build type. I want to use a default signingConfig for all other build variants.

i.e.

- flavor1Debug -> debugSigningConfig
- flavor1Release -> flavor1ReleaseSigningConfig
- flavor2Debug -> debugSigningConfig
- flavor2Release -> flavor2ReleaseSiginingConfig
- every other variant -> debugSigningConfig

Is this possible?